# Android Studio keeps showing my previous Android app

Tags: android, kotlin

[image: this is the design and I need to add two numbers using those texts]I'm new to Android developing.. I created a successful app and I started a new app as a new project in android studio. when I'm trying to run my new app, Emulator keeps showing me the previous app.. but showing errors in new app..What should I do?

And also I have another problem. I accidentally set textsize as 40 in a TextView, then I changed it to 40sp. but keep showing me a error "'40' is incompatible with attribute textSize (attr) dimension."

I tried restart Android studio,Emulator

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val firstNum = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.firstNumEditText)
        val secNum = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.secondNumEditText)
        val addBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.addButton)
        val resultTxtView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.resultTextView)



addBtn.setOnClickListener {
        resultTxtView.text = "Addition is "+(firstNum.text.toString().toInt()+secNum.text.toString().toInt()).toString()
        Toast.makeText(this,resultTxtView.text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        }
    }
}
```

error "'40' is incompatible with attribute textSize (attr) dimension."

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Calculator Application</string>
    <string name="First_number">Enter a number</string>
    <string name="Second_number">Enter a number</string>
    <string name="add">Add</string>
    <string name="result">Result</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: post the `activity_main.xml`

Comment: Are you trying to perform Addition of the texts? or just concat them as string?

Comment: please add size as : 40sp or 40px unit is necessary after size

Comment: want to add two numbers.. I know my logic was wrong.. I edited the question @RahulKhurana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean your Project Under Build>Clean Project after that Rebuild Project under Build>Rebuild Project. Also post which error you are getting while running the app.

Answer (score 1):

please add size as : 40sp or 40px unit is necessary after size

Comment: I already changed it as 40 as 40sp, also mentioned that in the post... but didn't work @neha

Answer (score 0):

I found all the errors

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val firstNum = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.firstNumEditText)
        val secNum = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.secondNumEditText)
        val addBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.addButton)
        val resultTxtView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.resultTextView)

        addBtn.setOnClickListener {
            resultTxtView.text = "Addition is "+(firstNum.text.toString().toInt()+secNum.text.toString().toInt()).toString()
            Toast.makeText(this,resultTxtView.text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        }
    }
}
```

[image: this is the output]